# How to delete current row with jquery datatable plugin

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables, rows, delete-row

I have a column with buttons in a table I'm using jQuery datatable plugin. The buttons say "Remove" and the idea is that when you click on that button it deletes the current row in the table.

When I call `fnDeleteRow` it seems to work the first time but no any further time for that row so it looks like its not really deleting the row properly.

Comment: Need more info.  Do you use ajax to populate your datatable or are you converting a static html table?  Also: why is the data no longer accurate? doesn't datatable move the tr (and corresponding id tags) on sort?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Try this:

```
var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
oTable.fnDeleteRow(oTable.fnGetPosition(row));
```

If it doesn't work, check the following [example](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/select_single_row.html)

Comment: +1 but I think closest would be a more appropriate selector than parents

Comment: i did switch it closest but after that it worked perfectly .. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you attached a function to be called when the user clicks on the button. The function would be something like this

```
function DeleteRow(event)
{
  //get the row of the cell that is clicked
  var $row = $(this).parents("tr").eq(0)
  //if you need the id you can get it as
  var rowid = $row.attr("id");
  //now you can call delete function on this row
  $row.delete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
    // Delete Row
    $('.glyphicon-minus').on("click", function() {
        configTable.row($(this).closest("tr").get(0)).remove().draw();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

from [this page](http://www.datatables.net/api):

```
$('#example tbody td').click( function () {
    /* Get the position of the current data from the node */
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition( this );

    //...
} );
```

Comment: but i am clicking on a button inside a table cell

Answer (score 0):

This is how it works for me. In document ready function I assign converted version of HTML table to a variable and when a button in the is clicked I go through parents/childs with JQuery and send the row you get as a parameter to the library's fnDeleteRow() function.

Here's is the comments from the library function. And an example that's mentioned in library.

```
/**
* Remove a row for the table
*  @param {mixed} target The index of the row from aoData to be deleted, or
*    the TR element you want to delete
*  @param {function|null} [callBack] Callback function
*  @param {bool} [redraw=true] Redraw the table or not
*  @returns {array} The row that was deleted
*  @dtopt API
*  @deprecated Since v1.10
*
*  @example
*    $(document).ready(function() {
*      var oTable = $('#example').dataTable();
*
*      // Immediately remove the first row
*      oTable.fnDeleteRow( 0 );
*    } );
*/

// And here's how it worked for me.
var oTable;
$("document").ready(function () {
    oTable = $("#myTable").dataTable();
});

//Remove/Delete button's click.
$("a[name='deleteColumn']").click(function () {
    var $row = $(this).parent().parent();
    oTable.fnDeleteRow($row);
});
```