# Delete row using Jquery Datatable Plugin by Id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The rows of `oTable` datatable has unique ids.

Why this code doesnt work?

```
oTable.fnDeleteRow(
    oTable.fnGetPosition(
        $('#row'+id+'-tr')));
```

the error is:

```
[18:10:44.631] nNode.nodeName is undefined @ http://localhost: ... /jquery.dataTables.js:1903
```

Thank you!

**edit:**

Example:

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <th>
    <td>Name </td>
    <td>Delete</td>
   </th>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr id="row0-tr">
    <td> Row 0 </td>
    <td> <Button onclick="deleteRow(0)"> - </td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="row1-tr">
    <td> Row 1 </td>
    <td> <Button onclick="deleteRow(1)"> - </td>
   </tr>

   <tr id="row2-tr">
    <td> Row 2 </td>
    <td> <Button onclick="deleteRow(2)"> - </td>
   </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

**edit 2:**

The real problem is: How to get row of table using `id`?

The method `fnGetPosition($('#row'+id+'-tr')` isn't returning row.

I put this code before calling fngetPosition: `console.log($('#row'+id+'-tr'))` and
returns: `({length:1, 0:({}), context:({}), selector:"#row1-tr"})`

Thanks for help!

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926183/how-to-delete-current-row-with-jquery-datatable-plugin#1926531

Comment: This question is about how to get row position using `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer:

```
oTable.fnDeleteRow(
    oTable.fnGetPosition(
        document.getElementById('#row'+id+'-tr')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the jquery.dataTables source code around line 1903, it seems to me that `$('#row'+id+'-tr')` does return an empty object in your case. This means that the selector does not exist on your page.

You can verify this by putting a `console.log($('#row'+id+'-tr'))` before the `oTable.fnDeleteRow(`

Comment: `console.log($('#row'+id+'-tr'))` returns: `({length:1, 0:({}), context:({}), selector:"#row1-tr"})`. Im new with jQuery. It is empty?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. The length is 1, but the element with id 0, contains an empty hash... The selector is correct, jQuery should return  this `<tr id="row1-tr">` element.