# Dynamically Add a Delete Row jQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, delete-row

I am trying to dynamically add a row to a table with an edit/delete column. When delete is clicked, I want to remove the clicked on row.

I have initialized my table and the data in the following way:

```
            $('#myTable').dataTable();


            $("#myTableAddButton").click(function () {
                var myVal1= $('#Val1').val();
                var myVal2= $('#Val2').val();
                var myVal3= $('#Val3').val();


                $('#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData([
                    myVal1,
                    myVal2,
                    myVal3,
                    '<a href="#" onclick="EditRow();return false;">Edit</a> / <a href="#" onclick="deleteRow();return false;">Delete</a>'
                ]);
```

Then my `DeleteRow()` function is simply:

```
function deleteContactRow() {
    //get the row of the cell that is clicked
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $row.delete();
}
```

But it seems as though row.delete is not a valid function. Is there an alternative method to delete the row?

EDIT: Both `$(this).remove()` and `$row.remove()` do not work

Comment: You mean http://api.jquery.com/remove ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete current row with jquery datatable plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926183/how-to-delete-current-row-with-jquery-datatable-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I think the magic you want is

```
$row.parentNode.removeChild($row);
```

Untested.

Answer (score 0):

**For DataTables 1.9.x**

```
function deleteContactRow() {
    //get the row of the cell that is clicked
    var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $('#myTable').dataTable().fnDeleteRow($row.get(0));
}
```

From the [manual](http://legacy.datatables.net/api):

> `fnDeleteRow` Removes a row for the table
>
> Input parameters:
> `{mixed}`: The index of the row from `aoData` to be deleted, or the `TR` element you want to delete
> `{function|null}`: Callback function
> `{bool} [default=true]`: Redraw the table or not
>
> Return parameter:
> `{array}`: The row that was deleted

See [fnDeleteRow](http://legacy.datatables.net/api) for more details.